# Trouble renewing my SSL certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-ssl

So my free SSL certificate from startcom expired, and I went to renew it.
I was given a choice of pasting in the contents of my csr, or generating a new one on their website, so I pasted in my csr. Went through the whole domain verification process, got a certificate and replaced my old certificate file with the new one.

I restarted apache and it `[fail]`ed.

In the logs I found this:

```
 [Thu Jun 16 07:08:28 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `mydomain.com' does NOT match server name!?
[error] Unable to configure RSA server private key
[error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

I made sure that the ServerName directive said mydomain.com. But it was still happening, so I assumed that maybe I had the wrong private key or the wrong csr somehow.

Meanwhile, I sent a request to startcom, and they're not getting back to me. So I tried two other free SSLs, comodo and rapidssl (freessl), followed all the instructions (including generating a new csr), and I'm still having the same issue,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the startcom certificate didn't work, but the other two didn't work because I had other virtualhosts referring to the old one.

Answer (score 1):

CommonName should match your *server* name. If your server is named `www.mydomain.com`, then put that as CommonName.

Comment: My ServerName is mydomain.com

Comment: No, not necessarily the ServerName what Apache is configured to have. What does `hostname` return?

Comment: Actually I don't think `hostname` has anything to do with this.